# PC based router/gateway that supports Lawful Intercept?

Tags: networking, router, traffic, network-traffic

Is there any PC-based router/shaper/gateway that supports [**traffic capture** / **traffic analysis**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer)?

i maintain an Internet gateway, and want to run all traffic through a PC (virtual or otherwise), and have it log packets (e.g. rolling 5 TB logs). i know many routers support capturing of *n* packets (e.g. `n=10000`), then letting me download them in `winpcap` or `WireShark` format. But i'd like something more robust; designed to log desired packets on an ongoing basis.

Is there any (free) system that supports traffic capture, and (as a bonus) analysis.

It would be even better if this software supported traffic shaping of IPv4/6 traffic, with deep packet inspection, protocol violations, fragmentation, etc.

Why?

- work at a company and need to monitor all Internet traffic for employees leaking company secrets
- am a parent, and want to monitor my children's Internet activity
- am a brick-and-mortar business that provides free WiFi and need to monitor Internet traffic for illegal activity
- work for the NSA, and need to capture all traffic so i can later look for potential terrorists
- i'm having intermittent MTU issues related to IPv6 traffic, and would like to reassemble traffic after the fact

i know i could install WireShark on my PC, and capture traffic that way. But i want to capture all traffic from all devices (e.g. iPods, iPads, Blackberrys, Nexii, e-readers, PlayStations, X-Boxes), from a central point, on a large server.

The server would either become everyone's default gateway, before it is passed onto the *"real"* router. Or the server would be the on the `WAN` side of the router, physically sending packets out the modem.

## Pictures

Pictures are pretty. Everyone loves pictures. i currently have a PC-based router that does DHCP, DNS, traffic shaping, and is the gateway to the Internet:

[image]

What i need is some appliance that can be the new *default gateway*, and perform all the desired monitoring:

[image]

## Bonus Reading

- [ManageEngine - PitStop](http://blogs.manageengine.com/netflowanalyzer/2009/12/15/network-traffic-analysis-packet-capture-or-netflow.html)
- [ManageEngine - NetFlow](http://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/netflow-traffic-analysis.html)
- [Paessler - PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg)
- [Manual traffic capture on Cisco routers](http://www.cciezone.com/?p=107)
- [winpcap remote capture](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__remote.html)

Answer (score 0):

Install Linux on a PC with two network cards.

Linux can do:

- routing/NAT
- firewalling/filtering, including filtering on bad protocols and doing a lot of things on incoming, routed, and outgoing traffic.
- traffic logging, i.e. Netflow (look into nfsen)
- packet capture (install Wireshark or its command line equivalent, tshark, or look into OpenCALEA)
- QoS (`tc` command)
- transparent bridging
- VPNs

None of the the above is trivial, especially the QoS part, but it's possible.